# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object. How to fix this issue?

Tags: python, pickle, bert-language-model, kaggle

I am trying to save a BERT model and am reaching the following error. I already tried using model.save(), but that gave me another error so I am trying to find a workaround.

Here is the code I used to save the model

```
tf.saved_model.save(bert_tf, 'my_model3')

loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('my_model3')

with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(loaded_model, f)
```

And here is the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[89], line 6
      3 loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('my_model3')
      5 with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as f:
----> 6     pickle.dump(loaded_model, f)

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'
```

For reference, here is the source notebook I am using (I have changed nothing except adding `from tensorflow import keras` in the beginning and the code above): https://www.kaggle.com/code/amirhoseinsedaghati/sentiment-analysis-on-reviews-mchcnn-bert-textblob

Could anyone give me some support?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, TensorFlow models cannot be directly pickled using 'pickle' due to compatible problems.

Instead of using pickle, you should use TensorFlow's built-in methods for saving and loading models.

Try with:

Save the Model:

```
tf.saved_model.save(bert_tf, 'my_model3')
```

Load the Model:

```
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('my_model3')
```

Comment: I want to save the model and load it in another notebook on Kaggle. Will this method still work?

Comment: It should work, if it does not work for you, you can try to save your model like "bert_tf.save('my_model3', save_format='tf')" and then load like "loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model3')". I hope it solve your issue.